# OpenGL shader, works using ./ but not opening .app in finder

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl

I'm teaching myself OpenGL and am having trouble get an example to work. Using the same source code, it builds and runs perfectly fine using MinGW under windows, and builds fine using g++ on mac. The example uses a vertex and a fragment shader to render a triangle to a window generated using GLFW. When I run the program using from terminal using `./tutorial2.app` it works as expected, but by opening the app from finder, or using `open tutorial2.app` doesn't work. It opens the window, and has the correct background colour, but it doesn't draw the triangle.

My guess is that it has something to do with the shader being used to draw the triangle. The example code uses `printf` to output the progress of the shader compilation. Using `./tutorial2.app` it prints this out to terminal as expected, but opening it from finder doesn't open a terminal window, and so doesn't print any potential error messages.

So my question is two fold. Is there a way to open (or build) my source code to open a terminal window so I can see the `printf` output other than using `./`? Secondly looking at my code, does anyone know what might be causing the triangle not to draw under some circumstances?

(I didn't include the code here because it's about 150 lines, but if I should let me know and I will)

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you're using a relative path, and they are relative to the working directory. If you move up a level (`cd ..`) in the Terminal and run from there (`directoryname/tutorial2.app`) it won't work either. The Mac way is to put the shaders inside the application bundle and use Cocoa functions to locate them.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. I found that by removing the `.app` extention I could get it to run and show the `printf` output. And the problem is indeed that it can't find the shader file. Is there a way to make the app bundle using my current makefile and source code configuration, or do I have to change the source?

Comment: Bundles are a pain to work with from the command-line. XCode makes them extremely easy, but that's all smoke and mirrors and you have to learn multiple tools such as `install_name_tool` and `otool` once you venture into writing your own Makefile to build your own .app bundle. Additionally you will need to learn about `.plist` files. Pointing you to a quickstart location feels almost impossible :-\ I can point you [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)
 and you will probably sink or swim.